# Convert one array to another with minimal quantity of splices

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, splice

Let's take, for example, this array

```
ar = [6,3,5,1,2]
```

I want to convert it to another array and I might use only two operations - insert item at specific position (splice(i,0,item)) or remove item from specific position (splice(i,1)). I'm looking for the solution that uses minimal quantity of theese splices.

The second important condition is that we consider arrays with unique values, our arrays don't contain doubles.

For example,

```
ar1 = [6,3,10,5,1,2];
ar2 = [6,3,1,2,5];
```

That's obvious that if we want to get ar1 from ar, we need only one splice - ar.splice(2,0,10). If we want to get ar2, we have to do two splices: ar.splice(2,1) and then push(5) (the second equals to splice(ar.length,0,5))

By the way, this task has natural practical value. Let's imagine, for example, list of products and product filter. We change filter's settings and the list changes respectively. And every change followed by beauty slow jquery slide up - slide down animation. This animation might slide up and hide specific item or insert and slide down a new one. The task is to minify the quantity of theese animations. That means we try to minify the quantity of DOM-manipulations of the list.

Comment: it can always be done in 1 splice - delete whole old array, insert new array. What exactly are you after?

Comment: You're right. I updated my question. I may use only splice of specific type that means each operation might be only removing or adding one item.

Comment: Can an array contain duplicate numbers?

Comment: No, it contains only unique ids, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote the code hopefully solving the problem. This code is somehow based on Levenshtein distance concept. It seems very useful for this problem, as was mentioned in maniek's answer.
For simplicity I've worked with strings instead the arrays and used Python.
It seems that original problem easily reduce to the same problem for two arrays of equal length consisting of the same set of integers. So, I assumed that the initial string and target string have the same length and consist of the same set of characters.
Python code:

```
import random
# Create random initial (strin) and target (strout) strings
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
l = list(s)
random.shuffle(l)
strout = ''.join(l)
random.shuffle(l)
strin = ''.join(l)

# Use it for tests
#strin = "63125798"
#strout = "63512897"

print strin, strout

ins_del = 0
for i in xrange(len(strin)-1, -1, -1):
    if strin[i] != strout[i]:
        if strin[i-1] == strout[i]:
            ii = strout.find(strin[i], 0, i)
            strin = strin[:ii] + strin[i] + strin[ii:i] + strin[i+1:]
            ins_del = ins_del + 1
            #Test output
            print "1:", strin
        else:
            ii = strin.find(strout[i], 0, i-1)
            strin = strin[:ii] + strin[ii+1:i+1] + strout[i] + strin[i+1:]
            ins_del = ins_del + 1
            #Test output
            print "2:", strin

print strin, strout

# Check the result
for i in xrange(0, len(strin)):
    if strin[i] != strout[i]:
        print "error in", i, "-th symbol"

print "Insert/Delite operations = ", ins_del
```

Example of output:

```
kewlciprdhfmovgyjbtazqusxn qjockmigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
2: kewlciprdhfmovgjbtazqusxny
1: kewlciprdhfmovgjbtazqusnxy
2: kewlciprhfmovgjbtazqusdnxy
2: kewlciphfmovgjbtazqursdnxy
2: kewlciphmovgjbtazqufrsdnxy
2: kewlciphmogjbtazquvfrsdnxy
2: kelciphmogjbtazquwvfrsdnxy
2: keciphmogjbtazqulwvfrsdnxy
2: kciphmogjbtazquelwvfrsdnxy
2: kciphmogjbazqutelwvfrsdnxy
2: kciphmogjbaquztelwvfrsdnxy
2: kciphmogjbquaztelwvfrsdnxy
1: qkciphmogjbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
2: qkcipmogjhbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
2: qkcimogjphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
1: qjkcimogphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
2: qjkcmoigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
1: qjokcmigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
1: qjockmigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
qjockmigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy qjockmigphbuaztelwvfrsdnxy
Insert/Delite operations =  19
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of operations is exactly the edit distance (if you disallow substitution). Look up  levenshtein distance.

You can modify the algorithm to calculate levenshtein distance to actually output the operations required.